# How to print multiple items from dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a VERY basic question here, so please don't laugh. I can't find any specific resolution to this, and the manual I am using does not address this question specifically, probably because it is something really obvious. When using:

> print residents['tenantA']

I get the correct output "**36**" from the dictionary

> residents = {'tenantA' : 36, 'tenantB' : 37, 'tenantC' : 38}

But when I try this with more than one item from the dictionary as follows:

> print residents['tenantB', 'tenantC']

I get the following error:

> KeyError: ('tenantB', 'tenantC')

I have also tried

> print residents['tenantB' + 'tenantC']

but as expected, this just concatenates **tenantB** and **tenantC** to **tenantBtenantC**.

I have also tried:

> print residents[1:]

but then I get the error

> TypeError: unhashable type

The error message does not tell me much. Could anyone let me know what I am missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Could you not just `print residents['tenantA']` then `print residents['tenantB']` ?

Comment: `for key in ('tenantB', 'tenantC'): print residents[key]`? See the tutorial on dictionaries: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: Or, just for fun, `operator.itemgetter('tenantB', 'tenantC')(residents)`. (There are some cases where this is the one obvious way to get a bunch of values from a dict, but this isn't one of them…)

Comment: **iwin:** The idea is to get them to print from one line of code (I think). **Korem:** This is in fact FROM a tutorial, but thanks for the suggestion anyway. **abarnert:** Thanks, haven't learnt that one yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
print residents['tenantB', 'tenantC']
```

This tells python to look for a key called `'tenantB', 'tenantC'`, and you don't have that key in your dict.

Probably you wanted this instead:

```
print residents['tenantB'], residents['tenantC']
```

Comment: Aha, so that's how it thinks! OK, thanks a lot wim, that definitely gets me the right output. Will accept as soon as 10 mins have elapsed.

Answer (score 4):

Python converts 'tenantB', 'tenantC' as a tuple and looks for tuple as a key for the dict. Which is evident from the error message,

```
KeyError: ('tenantB', 'tenantC')
```

You can see that the key is printed as tuple **('tenantB', 'tenantC')**.

Hence individual keys must be printed separately, like

`print residents['tenantB'], residents['tenantC']`

Comment: That explains it. Thanks a lot. Now I understand what the error meant.

Comment: Glad to have helped you

Answer (score 0):

In python3:

```
print(residents['tenantB'], residents['tenantC'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this page as I was struggling with the same issue for an online course I am doing. I'm a newbie of sorts and not been able to find anything so far in Google that indicates it's possible to pack multiple items in a print statement.

So the resolution I've worked out is as follows (am sure there is a better way, but not found it yet):

```
A1 = dictionary_name[entry No.]['key-1']
A2 = dictionary_name[entry No.]['key-2']
A3 = dictionary_name[entry No.]['key-3']

print(f"Compare A: {A1}, {A2}, {A3}")
```

The variables A1, A2 & A3 are assigned with the values of each key and print as this output:

Compare A: National Geographic, Magazine, United States